# SSH Connection disconnected

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx, ssh

I'm a student from korea

first, i'm sorry about my low level english :)

I'm make a web service using AWS + nginx + django

I connect to AWS instance(ubuntu) using SSH protocol

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-74-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

 System information as of Sat Apr 30 07:03:51 UTC 2016

 System load:  0.0               Processes:           105
 Usage of /:   23.8% of 7.74GB   Users logged in:     0
 Memory usage: 14%               IP address for eth0: 172.31.17.137
 Swap usage:   0%

 Graph this data and manage this system at:
    https://landscape.canonical.com/

 Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:
    http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud

21 packages can be updated.
17 updates are security updates.


Last login: Sat Apr 30 07:03:52 2016 from 210.103.124.253
pyenv-virtualenv: no virtualenv has been activated.
```

and

```
manage.py runserver --settings=abc.settings.production
```

So everyone can access my web service!

but.... after 30miniute

the SSL connection is broken itself....
export this message

```
packet_write_wait: Connection to 52.69.xxx.xxx: Broken pipe
```

and nobody can't access my web service...

so... my web site can't access when my computer was power off, none SSL connection...

I want everyone can access my web service 24/7

please give me a method thank you :)

Comment: Did you try to start your server with `nohup` (`nohup manage.py runserver --settings=abc.settings.production &`)?  This would ensure that the process continues even if your session is disconnected.

Comment: my command is (python manage.py runserver --settings=abc.settings.production)
Is your method (nohup python manage.py runserver --settings=abc.settings.production)?? @JuliePelletier

Comment: thank you!! Julie Pelletier!!
YOU SOLVED MY PROBLEM!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to run a command that continues after your current shell terminates, you should use the `nohup` command to launch it.

That causes the process to be detached from its initial parent shell so it is not killed when the parent terminates.